# Explanation of a sample circuit for the FL5160 dimmer controller

Tags: power, mosfet, ac, mosfet-driver

While looking for dimmer circuits, I stumbled upon the FL5160 dimmer controller and it's [specification](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FL5150-D.pdf).

The example schematic (for example, the 3-wire circuit on page 3) connects DC ground to the common terminals of two MOSFETs in series. It appears that when Q1 and Q2 conduct, there's no isolation between the AC mains and the DC part of the circuit.

Looking around, I see this is pretty common, for example, this [3-Wire Trailing-Edge Dimmer](https://sound-au.com/project157.htm) also has a 3-wire dimmer circuit that has the ground connected like that.

Am I understanding this correctly? Or is something like an optocoupler preferable here, assuming the dimming would be controlled by a human operator?

Answer (score 0):

Dim is controlled by a human operator via the Dim input, not via direct control of the MOSFETs with 120V across them.

Answer (score 0):

Operator safety is achieved by using a potentiometer with a plastic shaft, and optionally a special internal construction that guarantees a second layer of insulation. The housing for such a circuit will typically be plastic. So no need for an optocoupler as there are no external connections to the module apart from the two mains wires.